# Parse switching view controller on successful login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

After the user logs in SUCCESSFULLY, I need to switch view controllers to the timeline section of my app, this is also going to be a tab bar view controller with 5 different tabs at the bottom. Here is the code I have so far, it works and is connected to the parse database I have setup.
    import UIKit
    import Parse

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func loginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = usernameField.text
    let password = passwordField.text

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            println("Success")
        } else {
            var loginError:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid Login", message: "I did not recognize your credentials. Try again?", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")
            loginError.show()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func closeTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

In the line println("sucessful"), instead of printing out the sucessful login I need to switch to their timeline home (the tab bar view controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a segue to transition to new view controller if the login was successful:

```
if user != nil {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulLoginPage", sender: self)
```

}

Comment: Mind accepting my answer? Helps the community when others search for similar issue.

Comment: Yes sir, just did! Thanks again.